# Windows-10 SSH session to remote Windows machine disconnects on control-C; session to Linux VM doesn't

Tags: windows, ssh

I'm using `ssh` from a Windows-10 box in two ways:  one connects to a SSH server that I've installed on a remote Windows machine (Windows-8 I think...); one connects to a VirtualBox VM that's local.

When I press control-C, the Windows session disconnects.  The Linux session simply prints `^C`.

I'd like to keep the Windows-hosted session from disconnecting, too.  But, what and where's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for an answer to this one, but I did notice something unusual.  This particular machine has `sh` ... the Cygwin bash-shell.  And, if you enter *that* program, control-C no longer cuts the session!  As long as you stay in it.  (Although, as I've asked separately, it has other "issues" of its own having to do with backspace and arrow keys.)